# python | matplotlib | plt.fill_between two lines in a Circle

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

Hey can someone help me?

I want to fill the area between the lines. I have two areas finished, but the other one, I don't know how I do that.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constellation:
M = 8
A = 1 # Amplitude
m = np.arange(0,M) #all information symbols m={0,1,...,M-1}
I = A*np.cos(m/M*2*np.pi)
Q = A*np.sin(m/M*2*np.pi)
constellation = I + 1j*Q #reference constellation  

# Plotting the fig: 
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,10])

ax.plot([-1/2,0],[-1,0],'k--')
ax.plot([1/2,0],[-1,0],'k--')
ax.plot([1/2,0],[1,0],'k--')
ax.plot([-1/2,0],[1,0],'k--')

ax.plot([-1,0],[-1/2,0],'k--')
ax.plot([1,0],[1/2,0],'k--')
ax.plot([-1,0],[1/2,0],'k--')
ax.plot([1,0],[-1/2,0],'k--')

plt.fill_between([0,-1], [0,-1/2],[0,1/2],color='gray',alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between([0,1], [0,-1/2],[0,1/2],color='gray',alpha=0.5)



circle =  plt.Circle((0,0),1,color='k',linestyle='--',fill=False)
ax.add_patch(circle)



ax.scatter(np.real(constellation),np.imag(constellation),c='c',s=20**2)


ax.set_xlabel(r'I-Axis $Real\{x\}$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'Q-Axis $Imag\{x\}$')
plt.tight_layout();
```

and this is my current output:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbN9b.png)

Thanks!

Comment: it would be simpler if you would create minimal working code which would could copy and run.

Comment: Which other area are you trying to fill?

Comment: @furas sorry, I edit it. And I know it for the next question.

Comment: @Davide_sd, in the best all areas and I can edit than the alpha or the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is similar function `fill_betweenx(y, x1, x2)`

You can also use `plt.fill(x, y)` to fill `polygon`.

Doc: [fill_betweenx()](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_betweenx.html), [fill()](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10,10])

ax.plot([-1/2,0],[-1,0],'k--')
ax.plot([1/2,0],[-1,0],'k--')
ax.plot([1/2,0],[1,0],'k--')
ax.plot([-1/2,0],[1,0],'k--')

ax.plot([-1,0],[-1/2,0],'k--')
ax.plot([1,0],[1/2,0],'k--')
ax.plot([-1,0],[1/2,0],'k--')
ax.plot([1,0],[-1/2,0],'k--')

plt.fill_between([0,-1], [0,-1/2],[0,1/2],color='gray',alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between([0,1], [0,-1/2],[0,1/2],color='gray',alpha=0.5)

plt.fill_betweenx([0,-1],[0,-1/2],[0,1/2],color='green',alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_betweenx([0,1],[0,-1/2],[0,1/2],color='green',alpha=0.5)

plt.fill([-1, 0, -1/2], [-1/2, 0, -1], color='red',alpha=0.5)
plt.fill([1, 0, 1/2], [1/2, 0, 1], color='red',alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The problem was. I don't know that it give a fill_betweenx and fill function.